# Getting a single Json value in python

Tags: python, json, api, opensea

I have this API response, I want to take some values and store them as variables for a python BOT for example 'floor_price' (I want the integer after it ofc) but for some reason, it's not working it keeps giving me errors but when I try it with 'stats' it works and gives everything.

The API https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/collection/ogcats-harvest-galaxy/stats

```
url = "https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/collection/ogcats-harvest-galaxy/stats"

 headers = {"Accept": "application/json"}

response = requests.request("GET", url)
json_response = response.json()
 floor= json_response['floor_price']
```

pls help :)

Comment: If that snippet is exactly how the program runs, you’ll want to remove the single space indent of headers and floor

Comment: Surely it`ll be json_response["stats"]["floor_price"] no?

Comment: @kindall Thank you, works like charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
url = "https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/collection/ogcats-harvest-galaxy/stats"

headers = {"Accept": "application/json"}

response = requests.request("GET", url)
json_response = response.json()
floor= json_response['stats']['floor_price']
```

credits: @kindall

Comment: Got it from kindall, just reposting as an answer so its easier to find. If other people have the same question